# map reduce program to implement data structure in hadoop framework

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This is a data structure implementation in Hadoop. I want to implement indexing in Hadoop using map-reduce programming. 
Part 1 = I want to store this text file each word using index number in a table. [Able to complete]
Part 2 = Now I want to perform the hashing for this newly created table [not able to complete]
1st part I am able to complete but 2nd part I m facing difficulty  
Suppose if I have a text file containing 3 lines: 
    how is your job
    how  is your family 
    hi how are you

I want to store this text file using indexing. I have map-reduce code that returns index value of every word, this index value I am able to store in index table (hash table)
   Output that contains index values of every word:
how 0,
how 14,
is 3,
is 18,
job 12,
your 7,

Now to store in hash table apply hashing for every word (index value) with modules (number of distinct elements in file) let say 4. For every index value of word and apply hash function (modules'%') to store in hash table. If there is a collision for same location then go to next location and store it.

```
  0%4=0(store 'how' at hash index 0)
  14%4=2(store 'how' at has index 2)
  18%4=2(store 'is' at hash index 3 because of collision) 
  7%4=3 (store 'your' at index 4 because of collision)
```

Comment: As of my knowledge you can go with chain map reduce approach. can you post your input file and expected output.

Comment: let, text file containing 3 lines: 
    how is your job.
    how  is your family. 
    hi how are you.  step 1::  (solved) Output contains index values of word::are 38,hi 32,how 0,how 14,how 34,famly  26,is 3,is 18,job 12,  your 7,
step 2:(unsolved)store these index values in hash table using hashing technique: 0%4=0(store 'how' at hash index 0)
      14%4=2(store 'how' at has index 2)
      18%4=2(store 'is' at hash index 3 because of collision) 
      7%4=3 (store 'your' at index 4 because of collision) is this sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create Hashtable object and put the key and value.

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
```

How to find key?
Ans. you have total distinct words count and word's index.
      key = index % no of distinct word
      value = word

Before insert record in hashtable, check collision is occur or not for that key.
How can I check collision occur?
Ans.

```
boolean collision=hashtable.containsKey(key);
```

if collision is true, then linearly check for key+1, key+2,...and when you get collision is false, insert the key and value in hashtable using below line.

```
hashtable.put(key,value);
```

Comment: where should I need to write hash table logic(reducer or mapper)?

Comment: in a mapper you can write this logic. if you want to aggregate something, then u need reducer. Otherwise you can just write mapper. No need of reducer

Comment: I can store in the hashtable. But after that what you want to do?

Comment: I want to build my carrier in Hadoop, machine leaning, and artificial intelligence so I want to see the compatibility and extensibility of map-reduce programming with data structure other concepts. I am new in map-reduce programming and very curious to learn about its capabilities and functionalities. Would you like help me on the above problem and like to suggest me any web sites or any use full material that can be useful for me, thanks

Comment: can you tell procedure, to implement data structure(array, linked list, hashing ) in Hadoop using map-reduce programming .

Comment: map reduce is nothing but, implemented on top of java. So you can use all the data structures available in java such as arraylist, linkedlist, Map, Set etc. All data structures are the part of java collection framework.